# Including Google's gtag analytics via a config variable

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to setup the new Google analytics, and I'd like to change which `GA_TRACKING_ID` via a config.js for my Single Page app, depending on whether it is on our dev, staging, or production server.

We already use this config file to change which API our app hits, and can set the config `gtag('config', app.config.analyticsCode);` at runtime, but the script to GET the analytics js file seems to hardcode the ID in the request. `<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>`

Should I just use JS to write the  tag manually? Can I get the script without the tracking ID and initialize it with the `gtag()` command anyways? I couldn't find a way to do this on the Gtag dev docs site. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears it's possible to load the `gtag` script without defining a default tracking ID, which is what the `?id=GA_TRACKING_ID` URL parameter does.

You can then use:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID'); // replace GA_TRACKING_ID with your tracking ID
```

to set the default tracking ID for the property.

This is mentioned [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/):

> The following code in the snippet:
>
> ```
> gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');
> ```
>
> serves these purposes:
>
> - It configures the Google Analytics property with the tracking ID GA_TRACKING_ID as the default property to receive data sent by the event command.
> - It sends a pageview to the default property.

Comment: By golly, you're right! I should have just tried the gtag script request sans ID, since a quick test now shows that all the query parameter does is throw the parameter into the script itself. Thanks for the help. Gotta love undocumented features.